# Суммирование вводимых в цикле значений

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Price {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите количество запчастей:");
        int a = scan1.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Введите стоимость запчастей:");
                int b = scan1.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь написать небольшую программу для расчета прибыли. Вопрос как сделать так, чтобы введенные через консоль цифры, в разделе "Введите стоимость запчастей:" суммировались и в конце цикла выдавали сумму всех введенных чисел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо добавить переменную int, например, с именем sum:

```
public class Price {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите количество запчастей:");
        int a = scan1.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Введите стоимость запчастей:");
                int b = scan1.nextInt();
                sum += b;
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот моя реализация (с финтифлюшками)
[image: консоль]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        /*Для цвета в консоли*/
        String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
        String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
        String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
        /*Для цвета в консоли*/

        System.out.print("Введите стоимость запчасти:" );
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        while (console.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(ANSI_CYAN + "===============================" + ANSI_RESET);
            sum += console.nextInt();
            System.out.print(ANSI_GREEN +"\nСумма запчастей: " +  sum + ANSI_RESET);
            System.out.print("\nВведите стоимость запчасти:" );

        }
    }
```